# Undefined variable: form_data (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel

Controller store method:

```
public function store(Request $request){
   $request->validate([
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'number' => 'required|unique:crud|numeric',
      'message' => 'required',
   ]);

   Crud::create($form_data);

   return redirect('crud')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully');
}
```

Exception:

> Undefined variable: form_data

Comment: Please paste a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code, not just a picture of it.

Comment: You're using the `$form_data` variable, but you don't have it defined anywhere.

Comment: replace $form_date with $request->all();

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `$form_data` variable, but you never defined it in your function. Maybe you wanted to put the form data inside a variable, and then use it to store some data? If that's the case, do something like this:

```
$form_data = $request->input(); //Get form data from $request
Crud::create($form_data);
```